# Create HttpRequestHeaders from JObject

Tags: c#, json, header, json.net, httpclient

I've created an API for my desktop software to avoid coding and rebuilding  every time I want to make changes to the HttpClient headers, but I don't know how to create a custom HttpRequestHeader list and add it to the HttpClient as request headers.

I'm looking for a solution like this:

`clients.DefaultRequestHeaders = list_of_json_header_values;`

Here is what my code for making the request looks like so far:

```
public static string DownloadSource(string link)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClientHandler hch = new HttpClientHandler();
        hch.Proxy = null;
        hch.UseProxy = false;

        using (HttpClient clients = new HttpClient(hch))
        {
            //clients.DefaultRequestHeaders = list_of_json_header_values; ???

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = clients.GetAsync(link).Result)
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    return content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception _ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is how I get the headers from JSON:

```
var headers_json = "json here";
var objects = JObject.Parse(headers_json);

foreach (var item in objects["header_settings"])
{
    //list_of_json_header_values.Add(item.ToString()); ???
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Console output:

```
"Cache-Control": "no-cache"
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
"Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an extension method like this:

```
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static void AddHeadersFromJson(this HttpClient client, string json)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

        foreach (JProperty prop in obj["header_settings"].Children<JProperty>())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(prop.Name, (string)prop.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(hch))
{
    client.AddHeadersFromJson(headers_json);

    ...
}
```